# Bootstrap 4.5 Truncate Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, truncate

I want to use the out of the box truncate utility of Bootstrap 4.5 by truncating text that is too long for a given height.

- I want text to wrap
- And i want the text to truncate with an ellipsis if it is too high.

How to I truncate the paragraph 2 in the following example?
https://codepen.io/baszero/pen/oNbPMme

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="some-flex flex">
          <h5 class="text-truncate">Text 1 which is very wide in length, so it should get ellipsis</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="">
          <h5 class="text-truncate">Text 2 which is very wide in length, so it should get ellipsis</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div style="height:300px;overflow:hidden;">
          <h5 class="text-truncate">H5 TRUNCATE Text 3 which is very wide in length, so it should get ellipsis</h5>
      <p>Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 </p>
      <p>Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph Text 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for overflow that happens in the y-axis:

> The text-overflow property only affects content that is overflowing a
> block container element in its inline progression direction

As an aside, these are the styles `.text-truncate` class adds to the element.

```
.text-truncate {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I wonder if there is a clean elegant 2020-solution to this problem. I only found thousand of hacks which I don't like how they work.